# add routing to my webassembly app or urls from jsonfile the creates the side navmenu for my app

Tags: xamarin, uno-platform

I'm working on a Blazor WebAssembly app with just a client project. I have a sidebar menu with submenu items, and I'm trying to display the content of these submenu items inside an  tag in the main area.

However, I'm encountering issues with correctly displaying the URLs within the . It seems like there might be a misunderstanding with how iframes work or how to open URLs inside them.

Can anyone provide guidance or share insights on how to correctly set up and handle iframes in a Blazor WebAssembly app, specifically when dealing with submenu items?